# Openstreetmap координаты объекта (широта, долгота)

Tags: openstreetmap, карты, c#, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет, есть Windows приложение, в которое выводиться карта от http://www.openstreetmap.org. Необходимо реализовать перетаскивание отображаемой в приложении карты при помощи мыши. Т.е. пользователь может навести курсор на карту, нажать левую кнопку мыши - и таскать ее (карту) в разные стороны.

Проблема, которая у меня сейчас возникла заключается в том, что я не знаю как получить актуальные координаты карты относительно координат смещения курсора мыши.

Например, у пользователя отображен кусок карты с координатами объекта: **40.0400,-76.4160 (широта, долгота)**. Предположим, пользователь взялся за карту и потянул ее в некоторую строну, в результате мы получили координаты смещения мыши **5;4 (x;y)**.

Собственно сам вопрос, как получить новые координаты объекта (широту и долготу) с учетом масштаба (зума), в котором отображена карта в данный момент у пользователя в программе, плюс того смещения, которое он (пользователь) сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/ru/site/forusers/download.html) Вам поможет. 
В плагинах есть возможность подключения openstreetmap